# async/await fetch not triggered for HTTP

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x

I am new to building web-services, so apologies in advance if the question is off topic.

I am building a web-server which involves a UI client (Node JS) and a backend component (Python). The backend component communicates with the UI client through [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com). The whole service is a search capability for scientific articles.

When I run the service on my laptop everything goes fine: UI client (running on port 3000) communicates with the backend component (running on port 8000) using async await fetch and results are returned back and displayed to the user.

The code on the client side which triggers the request to the backend component looks like this:

```
let data = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/search?query=my_query&vertical=cord19")
                    .then(res => (res.ok ? res : Promise.reject(res)))
                    .then(res => res.json())
```

Next step was to deploy this to an EC2 instance and open the relevant ports so that this can be accessed by a security group. I opened the ports 22 (ssh), 80 (http), 3000 (custom tcp), 8000 (custom tcp). I launched the UI client on the instance and I can access it through any browser from the security group I specified (http://one-ip-in-the-group:3000/). Similarly, I launched the service too, on port 8000.

### The problem:

When I attempt to trigger a search from the UI in the browser, while the execution reaches the above snippet, it does not trigger a request for some inexplicable reason.

I have verified that the service is listening on port 8000 (opened up a Python interpreter from within the instance and fired a request, which goes fine).

It seems that fetch is not triggering?

If I replace the URL in the fetch with any other **http** URL, again a request is not triggered. If I replace the URL with any other **https** URL, it is triggered normally.

I have no idea why that happens, but any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the Python versions match? iirc, the async/await behavior changed in a very recent version of python.

Comment: Any errors in your browser console? My guess is that you are accessing your UI with an https URL, in which case there is no way to make a request to an http URL (for obvious security reasons)

Comment: @blex: Many thanks, I am accessing the UI using http // one-ip-in-the-group:3000/

Comment: @I am using Python version 3.7.7 in my laptop and version 3.6.4 in the  EC2 instance. I don't think this is an issue yet  because its the client side (written in node js) which is not triggering.

Comment: @blex: Copy-pasting the output from my browser console:

Comment: [Error] Origin http://xxxxxxxxxxx:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/search?query=hey&vertical=cord19 due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://xxxxxxxxxxx:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (search, line 0)

Comment: does anybody know what is Access-Control-Origin?

Comment: You need to enable them on your server so that your browser does not block the request (it's blocking it because your UI and backend are on different hosts and the server does not have an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header saying that the UI's host is allowed to make requests to it). You might find what you need here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/ (it looks like it's very well explained, actually)

Comment: @blex: Very grateful for the feedback, you are the first person that has helped now for days. My question (and apologies if its naive), is how do I enable them on the server? Through FastAPI? I already tried app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'] ) to allow for all origins but the problem still persists. Again, many thanks.

Comment: Want to come here for a chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217256/cors-problem

Comment: More than happy to!